# dual monitor: how to drag browser to external monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora, workspace

I connected an external monitor to a HDMI socket on my laptop running fedora. When I move my mouse to the rightmost the mouse will be visible on the external monitor. I can drag terminal to the external monitor screen, but I can't drag the Firefox window to the external monitor.

So, how can I drag my Firefox window to the external monitor?

I checked my laptop screen and the external monitor are in the same workspace, thus one solution could be to have two workspaces and put the external monitor in the second workspace.

Comment: Your trying to drag from the top of the window correct?

Comment: ah, ok, I can drag it now, thanks! but is it possible to put two screens on two workspaces?

Comment: No problem! I'll make it an answer.

Comment: You can have two windows open; or you can set your extended desktop to clone instead (this will show the same thing on both screens)

Comment: can you give some steps/operations to follow?

Comment: Activities (upper left corner in your Desktop) --> Applications --> System Settings --> Displays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the top of the window and drag to the other screen.

or

Activities (upper left corner in your Desktop) --> Applications --> System Settings --> Displays